# What can I do if one coauthor tries to prevent a journal paper from being published?

Tags: publications, research-process, authorship, conflict-of-interest

I was a PhD student and was supervised by one bad supervisor. Our relationship broke up at the time when I tried to graduate. After a "fighting", I successfully graduated. But I left 10 unpublished paper to him. I had no time to publish these paper before I graduate. I put my supervisor's name there because he was my supervisor. I didn't really contribute to the paper.

I'm sure the 10 paper can be published as high quality journal paper because I'm currently working as a staff in another University. I've published a lot paper expect for those 10 so I know what paper can be published. But as the coauthor, my ex-supervisor "refused" to publish these paper. He always told me he needed to have a look, and nothing else happened. Every time I contact him, he would propose some unreasonable questions or tell me to wait for some time to put off the publication and no reply at all after that. It has been 2 years up to now. None of my 10 paper has been submitted yet. He obviously doesn't need the paper as a professor, but I need them desperately as a new lecture.

I've waited for 2 years for the first out of the 10 paper to be submitted. I couldn't wait for 20 years for the 10 paper to be submitted. He doesn't say he want to delete his name from this paper but I have sufficient reason to believe that he doesn't want me to publish these paper. He warned me that I couldn't submit the paper without his agreement otherwise he would withdraw the paper. My question is can I kick him out from the coauthor list and publish the paper by myself? Or is there any other suggestion say contacting the University about this situation to solve the problem?

I'm quite annoying as if I couldn't get rid of him even after I graduate and got my own position. Can anyone help please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You wrote "I put my supervisor's name there because he was my supervisor. I didn't really contribute to the paper." The second sentence seems to be at odds with the first. Did you mean "**My supervisor** didn't really contribute to the paper"?

Comment: I do not wish to be pessimistic or something similar, but are you sure your advisor is not stopping the publications because of the quality of the paper? Finishing a Ph.D with 10 publications is  a very rare fact (at least in North America), so I am quite surprised that someone could have publishes and have 10 unpublished, fully written papers, just laying there waiting to be submitted...

Comment: @BlaisB: *Finishing a Ph.D with 10 publications is a very rare fact (at least in North America)* Not true in my experience, which is in experimental nuclear physics in the US. However, it would be unusual to have 10 publications as first author.

Comment: In the present case it seems clear from the author question that he is first author. Obviously if this is not the case then yes, 10 papers is doable. Still, this would be for a limited number of fields...

Comment: oh my, dealing with peer review on ten papers at once seems like a nightmare....

Comment: @BlaisB _Finishing a Ph.D with 10 publications is a very rare fact (at least in North America)_ — Not in computer science.  Not even in theoretical computer science.